# HTTP Post in Swift 3 using concatenated string as URL

Tags: swift, http, post

Trying to post xml to a smart TV to change the channel. I'm trying to create my first ever app in Swift to achieve this.

So far, it's proved to be incredibly difficult – running into errors constantly. I had a dictionary, but it didn't work. Here's the most simple version of my code:

```
@IBAction func SelectButtonA(_ sender: NSButton) {
    let prefix = "http://"
    var ip = "192.168.2.7"
    let suffix = "/sony/IRCC?"
    let url = prefix + ip + suffix as String
    let session = URLSession.shared
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"

    let postData = "<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" s:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"><s:Body><u:X_SendIRCC xmlns:u="urn:schemas-sony-com:service:IRCC:1"><IRCCCode>AAAAAQAAAAEAAAAQAw==</IRCCCode></u:X_SendIRCC></s:Body></s:Envelope>"
}
```

How do I concatenate line 5 as a String, and not throw the error "Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type 'URL'" on line 7?

Comment: you need to init an URL instance. URL(string: url) i think

Comment: @koropok: Yes, you think the right thing :-) Just write (line 7) `var request = URLRequest(url: URL(url))` (New world record: 4xURL in one line of code)